# How to store table rows in a temp table

Tags: sql-server-2012, identity, temp-tables

I have a table with around 600000 records. I want to reseed the identity column of this table. Here's my plan:

1. Store contents of this table in temp table
2. Delete all records from this table
3. Reseed identity
4. Insert records from that temp table into this one

So how do I store this table into a temp one?

Comment: And why not just delete identity, update ids and reseed from 600001?

Comment: If you want to do it by deleting everything, you can populate a new table with the existing data using a `SELECT ... INTO` clause.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am using int as identity and its limit has been reached because the job that inserts record in this table, constantly delete old records and insert new ones. Since we moved this table from Dev to Production so identity was already very high because of constant delete and insert during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing else behind the scene then try this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE_NAME ON
GO

UPDATE  CTE
SET     ID = RN
FROM
(
    SELECT  ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM    TABLE_NAME
) AS CTE

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE_NAME OFF
GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT('TABLE_NAME', RESEED, 600001)
GO
```